# Trouble reading from json file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, mvvm

I know next to nothing about ajax and json.  Right now I'm trying to read the data from dealerData.json into my MVVM viewModel and 'data' keeps coming back as undefined.

```
$(function () {
    var obj;
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/Scripts/dealerData.json",
        success: function (data) {
            obj = JSON.parse(data);            
        }
    });

    ko.applyBindings(DealerNumberLotNumberViewModel(obj));
});
```

Comment: Did you check what data has? as in try to print out data on console

Comment: Whatever you need to do with the data needs to happen inside that success handler.

Comment: can your JS code access the json file? This is where error handler in ajax might have been useful. Add an error handler and then try. Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Added the error handler and I keep getting a 404 for some reason, tried altering the file path to no avail :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
  $(function () {
        var obj;
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/Scripts/dealerData.json",
        })
            .done(function (data) {
                obj = JSON.parse(data);
                ko.applyBindings(DealerNumberLotNumberViewModel(obj));
            });
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

ko.applyBindings(DealerNumberLotNumberViewModel(obj)); - this should go inside the callback method though like this -

```
$(function () {
var obj;
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/Scripts/dealerData.json",
    success: function (data) {
        obj = JSON.parse(data);
        ko.applyBindings(DealerNumberLotNumberViewModel(obj)); 

    }
});
```

Because obj is undefined till the callback method "success" actually assigns it something. and ko.applyBinding method should execute once obj is defined. Hence, it should go inside the callback method.

Also, it is a good idea to always have a failure callback method, just so that any failure doesn't go uncaught.

```
$(function () {
var obj;
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/Scripts/dealerData.json",
    success: function (data) {
        obj = JSON.parse(data);
        ko.applyBindings(DealerNumberLotNumberViewModel(obj)); 

    },
    error: function(args) {
     console.log('error occured: '+ args);
    }
});
```

Hope, this helps

Comment: I tried that. It shouldn't make a difference if I assigned the data to the global var obj.

Comment: No No, it will make a difference because the callback method is asynchronous and it will execute after  ko.applyBindings(DealerNumberLotNumberViewModel(obj)); . In that case obj is undefined for your view model

Comment: ohh may be there is some failure. Y don't you add a failure callback and see if that gets called. I will update that in my answer

Comment: I keep getting a 404.  My path is probably wrong, but I've tried "Scripts/dealerData.json" & "/Scripts/dealerData.json" sooooooo, i'm not sure

Comment: where is your dealerData.json located relative the the file where this code is? If these both files are in same folder. give this path = "dealerData.json"

Comment: I tried that before and got the same error then also.

Comment: try this - "../dealerData.json"

Comment: Did you check if the spellings are correct and extensions of the file and path as well?

Comment: I copy pasted the file name XD, and they were indeed in the same folder

Comment: I don't think that this likes me.